# Quadratic (programming) Optimization : Multiply by scalar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have two - likely simple - questions that are bothering me, both related to quadratic programming:

1). There are two "standard" forms of the objective function I have found, differing by multiplication of negative 1.

In the R package quadprog, the objective function to be minimized is given as −dTb+12bTDb and in Matlab the objective is given as dTb+12bTDb. How can these be the same? It seems that one has been multiplied through by a negative 1 (which as I understand it would change from a min problem to a max problem.

2). Related to the first question, in the case of using quadprog for minimizing least squares, in order to get the objective function to match the standard form, it is necessary to multiply the objective by a positive 2. Does multiplication by a positive number not change the solution?

EDIT: I had the wrong sign for the Matlab objective function.

Comment: Please add the sample data not as an image but as a text table.

Answer (score 0):

Function f(b)=dTb is a linear function thus it is both convex and concave. From optimization standpoint it means you can maximize or minimize it. Nevertheless minimizer of −dTb+12bTDb will be different from dTb+12bTDb, because there is additional quadratic term. Matlab implementation will find the one with plus sign. So if you are using different optimization software you will need to change d→−d to get the same result.

Comment: I can rewrite your query if you provide the script to create the data and the full query. Consider using https://dbfiddle.uk/ (or any other such service) to create a fiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Did you fix the issue with 181?

Comment: That I understand, but  that is not what I asked. Did you fix the issue that I mentioned in my answer, point (2)?

Comment: Just make sure that they are consistent. Did you see what the problem was?

Comment: ... I mean: did you fix the *wrong* `> 181` and replaced it with `> 180`?

Comment: Yes that is the same in integer arithmetic. So did you?

Answer (score 0):

1. The function −dTb+12bTDb where D is symmetric and convex and thus has unique minimum. In general that is called standard quadratic programming form, but that doesn't really matter. The other function dTb−12bTDb is concave function which has unique maximum. It is easy to show that for, say, bounded function f(x) from above the following holds:
   argmaxxf=argminx−f
   Using the identity above value b∗1 where −dTb+12bTDb achieves minimum is the same as the value b∗2 which achieves maximum at dTb−12bTDb, that is b∗1=b∗2.

Programmatically it doesn't matter if you are minimizing −dTb+12bTDb or maximizing the other one. These are implementation-dependent details.

2. No it does not. ∀α>0 if x∗=argmaxxf(x), then x∗=argmaxxαf(x). This can be showed by contradiction.